# Which function should I use to load the xml file generated by traincascade in openCV?

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, object-detection, haar-classifier, cascade-classifier

I have 1300+ positive images and 20000+ negative images.
My positive images are of size 1080*1920 but I create samples with them to 45*45:

```
opencv_createsamples -vec pos.vec -info posdata.txt -bg negdata.txt -w 45 -h 45 -num 1152
```

Then when I use opencv_cascadetrain,

```
opencv_traincascade -data xml -vec pos.vec -bg negdata.txt -numPos 1000 -numNeg 1000 -numStages 10 -featureType HOG -minHitRate 0.99 -w 50 -h 50
```

Then I want to use the cascade.xml file to detect my objects, should I use **CascadeClassifier or HOGDescriptor**? What's the difference? Where can I set the "nLevel"?

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

For loading a CascadeClassifier, you need to use the *load* function, which returns a bool. "It can be either a Haar or a LBP classifer"

You can look at an exemple here: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html

Comment: But I'm using HOG as the feature type?